# opencv shape detection in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

1st I know this post is duplicate.but that threads are not helpful to me.

I want detect shape and convert text in that shape to text file. This is my image .[image: ER.png]

I want to get that ER table to text file like this.

> customer-cid,cfName,cLName,...

I tried this tutorial [detect shape](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/)

but I couldn't detect any shapes.

It detect shapes as shown in image below

[image: detect shape ER.png]

any help is appreciated

Comment: It helps when you post the code you have tried so far, So people understand what could be the problem... sometimes is missing a step or tuning a parameter to work

Comment: The algorithms work for white objects on the black background. So inverse it first.

Comment: That code only finds external contours. The top level of contours is around white objects on black background, hence a single contour around your white picture is returned. Invert the image for processing to solve the issue. | The next problem you'll probably run into is those lines attached to the shapes. To deal with that, you may want to get the whole contour hierarchy and analyze the internal contours (the white "filling" of the shapes).

Comment: thanx for all its very helpful